# Dumping SQL queries to the screen in Laravel

Tags: mysql, debugging, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to output the actual SQL queries to the screen. I've added the following route:

```
// Display all SQL executed in Eloquent
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
{
    var_dump($query);
});
```

This works mostly, but some values come out as question marks:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`created_at`),'%b %d') as `date`, created_at, COUNT(*) as `count` 
from `contacts` 
where `created_at` > ? and `list_name` = ? or `list_name` = ? or `list_name` = ? 
group by `date` 
order by `created_at` asc
```

Is there a way to get the full query to output the actual values I'm dynamically adding, rather than unhelpful '?' characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use this code:

```
Event::listen(
    'illuminate.query',
    function ($sql, $bindings, $time) {
        $sql = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', "'%s'"), $sql);
        $full_sql = vsprintf($sql, $bindings);

        file_put_contents(storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'logs'
            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sql_log.sql', $full_sql . ";\n",
            FILE_APPEND);
    }
);
```

In mine I save output to file in local environment, you can of course display this query on screen.

Comment: Thanks very much Marcin, that was FAST

Comment: @ChrisJAllen I've just needed to copy it from my code :)