# Optimizing Queries - Eager loading takes too much memory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have following tables:

- User (about 1.000 rows)
- Fans (about 100.000 rows) - a User has many fans, a Fan belongs to one User
- Likes (about 100.000 rows - a User has many likes, a Like belongs to one User

Now I want to have a table with

- User name
- Number of fans
- Number of likes

It is a big table and I use jQuery DataTable to have it with pagnition but this here is about the server side.

I have set up all my relations and out put the table:

```
$users = User::get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
echo $user->name;
echo $user->fans()->count();
echo $user->likes()->count();
}
```

This is a lot of queries and I want to optimize. My first try was using Eager Loading.

```
$users = User::with('fans', 'likes')->get();
```

But this seems to be very havy for the server memory. On my local environment I have 16 MB memoriy size for php scripts. And it always tries to allocate more.

Is this normal?
Is the best solution to simply give the scripts more memory?
How else could I optimize my queries?

Comment: 16mb for a php script? that's not a lot at all.

Comment: Yeah, [the default](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production) is 128 MB.

Comment: Are you paginating your queries (using limits and offsets) as well or just pulling it all out and then sorting in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to count number of records there's no point to get all records just to count them, Now you get 201000 rows. You should add :

```
public function fansCountRelation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Fan')->selectRaw('user_id, count(*) as count')
        ->groupBy('user_id');
}


public function likesCountRelation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Like')->selectRaw('user_id, count(*) as count')
        ->groupBy('user_id');
}

public function getLikesCountAttribute()
{

    return $this->likesCountRelation ?
        $this->likesCountRelation->count : 0;
}

public function getFansCountAttribute()
{

    return $this->fansCountRelation ?
        $this->fansCountRelation->count : 0;
}
```

to your `User` model and now you will get only 1000 user rows + aggregate data for fans and likes.

And now you can use:

```
$users = User::with('fansCountRelation', 'likesCountRelation')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
    echo $user->likes_count;
    echo $user->fans_count;
}
```

However you should rethink if you really need it. 1000 rows for normal usage is too much. If you use it for export purposes that's fine, but if you only display it in admin panel for example, you should use paginating for that.

And in case it takes you much time, you should make sure you have indexes for your `fans` and `likes` tables for `user_id` column. It should speed up your queries a lot.

Comment: Thanks this works. No my memory is enough but the speed is even worse than without Eager Loading. Without it took 2.5 sec. now with Eader Loading it takes 3.6 sec.

Comment: @almo Do you have indexes for `fans` and `likes` tables on `user_id` columns? If not you should create them.

Comment: @Nabialek, yes I have indexes.

Comment: @almo You should then check your SQL queries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232815/dumping-sql-queries-to-the-screen-in-laravel/26232871#26232871 and check them in phpmyadmin using `EXPLAIN` to check what is happening. Also make sure you use `with` as I showed in my answer

Comment: @almo You could also check time if you don't use `with` and don't use likes_count and fans_count and if it's low to check time for those 2 relations separately because maybe problem is only for one of them or it's rather database server problem

Comment: Thanks! added a listener and there was acutally one more nested query that I had forgotten. Now I implementing all the details I got it down to 1.2 from which not everything is due to the Queries.